# How to get CQL change detail via cassandra 3.1 trigger?

Tags: triggers, cassandra

In cassandra 2.2, we can iterate update to get the cell change value:

```
for (Cell cell : update)
    {
        // Skip the row marker and other empty values, since they lead to an empty key.
        if (cell.value().remaining() > 0)
        {
            Mutation mutation = new Mutation(indexKeySpace, cell.value());
            mutation.add(indexColumnFamily, cell.name(), key, System.currentTimeMillis());
            mutations.add(mutation);
        }
    }
```

In cassandra 3.0, the ITrigger interface was changed, and the current object is change to "Partition update":

```
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update)
```

If anyone know what's the proper way to extract the detail change value of each cell?

Comment: Cassandra Trigger function interface is changed in cassandra 3.0. I am trying to use this "Trigger" function to catch data change event in Cassandra cluster and allow me to broadcast the change event to Kafka for streaming analytic process. The concept is similar like RethinkDB changefeed or MongoDB oplog.